# How to allow a dot in url htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm starting out with php and I want to use a dot (.) in url. For example someone with username test.test1 should point me out to a profile of a user with that username but I get an error message saying object not found. However I if I use letters,numbers, dash or underscore it works just fine. 
[image: Here it is working perfectly fine]

**But this is what happens when I use a dot in url:**
[image]

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

This is all the .htaccess code I have.

Comment: there is no dot in your rule

Answer (score 6):

Your Regular Expression doesn't match dots.

The sequence of characters between brackets mean "Match only these characters once", and the `+` out of it means "Match more than one times". So only characters defined between brackets are matched in the requested URL, which won't contain dots. You should add the "dot character" in your sequence of characters.

So your regex from `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` should become `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)$`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

Also to not match paths that actually exist as files or directories, use these conditions before rules that nearly match "everything", including your rewrite target (`profile.php`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The final .htaccess will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# this rule should not match existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1

# this rule should not match existing directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

---

P.S: I recommend you read some articles about Regular Expressions and use a "Regex Tester" to learn about regular expressions. For example, [this site](https://regexone.com) is a good starting point, and [this](https://regex101.com/) is a good online tester.

Comment: I copied the code you wrote and I got server error (500) for every page. I used the regex tester and it works fine. What may be the error?

Comment: _“but you should also keep in mind that a dot has the meaning of "every character found" in regex”_ - not inside a character class, which you have here. This dot does _not_ need escaping.

Comment: @AndrejAntevski _“What may be the error?”_ - please do not ever ask about a 500 error, without consulting your server’s error log first! In this case, you will likely find a message in there, saying something along the lines of “Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects”. Rewriting configured in .htaccess “loops”, using the new internal URI, until none of the rules match any more. By adding the dot to the list of possible characters, your rule now matches `profile.php` as well, so you created an endless loop.

Comment: You will need to add a `RewriteCond` that prevents the following rule from redirecting in that case, either by specifically checking that the request was not for `profile.php`, or by more generally checking if what was requested does not match a physically existing file.